# How to add User to another User "friends" field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a User model on my server-side, it looks like this:

```
const schema = new Schema({
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String
    },
    email: {
      type: String
    },
    avatar: {
      type: String
    },
    friends: [{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User'
    }]
  })
```

And I have different pages for logged user and for user which could be added to friends list by another user. I have a "Add to friends" button, by clicking it the User should be added into "friends" field to the User who clicked the button.

This how I get all the users from friends field from a User:

```
api.get('/data/getfriends', async (req, res) => {
    const userID = req.query.userID
    const User = ctx.models.User

    try {
      const friends = await User.findByID({_id: userID}).populate('friends')
      return res.json({
        friends
      })
    } catch (err) {
      return err
    }
  })
```

And this is a route where I should add a User to another User "friends" field:

```
 api.get('/data/friendship', async (req, res) => {

  })
```

But I do not know how actually ADD to a User to this field by clicking a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Edited
I havent noticed your array is just an array of ID's.
In this case, you should try $push.

```
User.update({'_id': uid}, {'$push': {'friends': id}});
```

You can also use User.findOneAndUpdate instead of User.update, since you are most likely updating just a single user at a time :)

Comment: I wil try this.

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you!